# Embed signed hash to pdf - Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed

Tags: java, pdf, itext, sign, digital

I have gone through similar postings in stackoverflow, but still no luck!

I'm generating a hash value for a pdf file, sending it to a signing server, and get back the returned signed hash, and try to attach it to the original pdf.

When validating the signature of the signed pdf in adobe reader, I get the warning "**Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed**". Everything else (signer's identity, timestamp, certificate) looks ok.

Here's what I'm doing (the signed hash is stored in `hashedSignature`)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baos, '\0');

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400, 20, 200, 80);   
        
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason(reason);
appearance.setLocation(location);
appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, 1, signatureFieldName);
appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);     
  
try
{
    appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
    appearance.setSignatureGraphic(Image.getInstance("[path to image file]");
}
catch (Exception e)
{ 
    appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
}
        
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
dic.setReason(appearance.getReason());
dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
dic.setContact(appearance.getContact());
dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()));
appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
      
HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, Integer.valueOf(8192 * 2 + 2));
appearance.preClose(exc);
        
ExternalDigest externalDigest = new ExternalDigest() 
{
    public MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String hashAlgorithm)  throws GeneralSecurityException 
    {
        return DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, null);
    }
};
       
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, externalDigest, false);

OCSPVerifier ocspVerifier = new OCSPVerifier(null, null);
OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(ocspVerifier);
byte[] ocsp = null;
if (chain.length >= 2 && ocspClient != null) 
{
     ocsp = ocspClient.getEncoded((X509Certificate) chain[0], (X509Certificate) chain[1], null);
}

ByteArrayOutputStream os = baos;
byte[] signedHash = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(hashedSignature.getBytes());

       
sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHash, null, "RSA");
Collection<byte[]> crlBytes = null;
TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient = new 
TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://timestamp.gdca.com.cn/tsa", null, null);

byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(signedHash, tsaClient, ocsp, crlBytes, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
System.arraycopy(encodedSig, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedSig.length);
PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));

try 
{
    appearance.close(dic2);
} 
catch (DocumentException e) 
{
    throw new IOException(e);
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest));
os.writeTo(fos);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What hash are you signing? You are aware that in the course of your code the PDF is prepared for signing? That includes adding some content to it which is part of the content to hash. Apparently, though, you don't hash this prepared PDF but some other, irrelevant data.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. So, is there something I can do to the existing code, or do I need to generate the hash and send it for signing after the pdf has been prepared? Thanks

Comment: First of all, it looks like you use a signature service which generates regular RSA-with-PKCS1-v1.5-padding signatures. Thus, you can easily use the more high-level signing API in the `MakeSignature` class instead of the manual `PdfPKCS7` class usage, can you not?